# perl script keeps reading data from STDIN

Tags: perl, stdin, pipe

I have 2 scripts for a task.

The 1st outputs lines of data (terminated with RT/LF) to STDOUT now and then.

The 2nd keeps reading data from STDIN for further processing in the following way:

```
use strict; 
my $dataline; 
while(1) { 
    $dtaline = ""; 
    $dataline = <STDIN>; 
    until( $dataline ne "") { 
        sleep(1); 
        $dataline = <STDIN>; 
    }

    #further processing with a non-empty data line follows   
} 

print "quitting...\n";
```

I redirect the output from the 1st to the 2nd using pipe as following: perl scrt1 |perl scpt2.

But the problem I'm having with these 2 scpts is that it looks like that the 2nd scpt keeps getting the initial load of lines of data from the 1st scpt if there's no data anymore after the initial load.

Wonder if anybody having similar experiences can kindly help a bit?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be making this much more complicated than it needs to be.  Perl normally uses blocking I/O, which means that `<STDIN>` won't return until there's a complete line of input.

```
use strict; 
use warnings; # use this too

while (my $dataline = <STDIN>) {
  #further processing with a non-empty data line follows   
}

print "quitting...\n";
```

When there's no more input (in your example, when scrt1 exits), `<STDIN>` returns `undef`, which will exit the `while` loop.  (Perl adds an implicit `defined` test to `while ($var = <>)` loops.)

Comment: Both scripts are meant to run all the time. And when it comes to the 2nd script, it should just sleep for a while when it polls no data from the previous one and start over again and again after sleeping.

Comment: @w2j3s8, polling is only needed with non-blocking I/O.  Reading from STDIN is normally blocking, so you don't need to do anything special to wait for more input.  When script 2 reads from STDIN, and no input is available, it automatically waits for more input.

Comment: @cjm,No it's not working: the 2nd script still is getting the same data again and again. Just here i'm not allowed to copy and paste all the output.

Comment: @cjm, I managed to do some more filtering with just 1 line remaining:  20101128T14:16:43 debug: line=<cp curve_name="EUR_SWAPS" id="STUB_5" stub="1" dt="20451229" rt="0.0347576" df="0.311762" zrt="0.0332796" live_rt="0"/> 20101128T14:17:0 debug: line=<cp curve_name="EUR_SWAPS" id="STUB_5" stub="1" dt="20451229" rt="0.0347576" df="0.311762" zrt="0.0332796" live_rt="0"/> 20101128T14:17:0 debug: line=<cp curve_name="EUR_SWAPS" id="STUB_5" stub="1" dt="20451229" rt="0.0347576" df="0.311762" zrt="0.0332796" live_rt="0"/>

Comment: @cjm, sorry i don't know how to get the formatting work here. just look at the "id" values - these lines are the same.

Comment: @cjm, but frankly I circumvented this issue by redirecting the output of the 1st script into a local text file and then "cat" the contents of that text file into the 2nd script. the "cat" way works for me. but it's troublesome: i need to use an intermediate file now.

Comment: @cjm, it's like: perl script1 > output.text &; cat output.text |perl script2 &; I'm running 2 processes in the background continuously.